# VS dot Net C# "String or binary data would be truncated"

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[PS_ALBUM_GUARDAR]
@COD_PERSONA    char (9), 
@FOTOGRAFIA     varbinary (max), 
@TIPO           char (2) 
as 
begin

set nocount off;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ALBUM] 
([COD_PERSONA], [FOTOGRAFIA], [TIPO], [AU_FEC_INSERT], [AU_USU_INSERT])
VALUES 
(@COD_PERSONA, @FOTOGRAFIA, @TIPO, GETDATE (), SYSTEM_USER)

end 
go
```

Si lo ejecuto desde SQL Server no hay ningún problema, todo marcha bien. El problema está cuando lo ejecuto desde Visual Studio (2015), genera una excepción interna, es decir es una excepción que ocurre en SQL Server al ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado.

> Excepción: String or binary data would be truncated.

Obviamente verifiqué los valores de los campos de tipo CHAR, ambos están bien, se envían a como fueron definidos, lo que me hace pensar que puede ser el campo FOTOGRAFIA, que es de tipo VARBINARY (MAX), tanto en la definición de la tabla como en la definición de parámetro.

Lo que más llama mi atención es que funciona al ejecutarlo desde SQL Server, no así desde VS, además que hace algunos meses ejecuté el proyecto y todo marchó bien, cabe aclarar que nada ha sido modificado, ni en la base de datos, ni en el código fuente en VS. Y esto último me consta porque soy el único con acceso a este código.

Normalmente soluciono mis cosas probando y echando a perder, pero ahora busco ayuda aquí pues no manejo mucho las excepciones con el tipo VARBINARY, dicho de otra forma, jamás he tenido problemas con este tipo de datos.

> Código en C#:

```
internal bool AddPhotoAlbum (string argCodPersona, byte[] inputBlob, string argTipoFoto)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connection...")))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("PS_ALBUM_GUARDAR", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_PERSONA", argCodPersona);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FOTOGRAFIA", inputBlob);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIPO", argTipoFoto);

                        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                OnDisplayException(new ExceptionEventArgs(e.Message));
                return false;
            }
        }
```

> Ejecución desde VS:

```
var bytes = ReadFromFile ("C:\foto.jpg");
var res =AddPhotoAlbum ("019000010", bytes, "FT");
```

Cualquier opinión es bienvenida.
Saludos.

Comment: Estás seguro que no son las columnas COD_PERSONA o TIPO las del problema?

Comment: Totalmente seguro. COD_PERSONA es de tipo CHAR (9), y TIPO es de tipo CHAR (2). Lo que se me acaba de ocurrir ahora mismo es utilizar SQL Server Profiler, para ver la ejecución del procedimiento en RunTime.

Comment: He probado extrayendo el script T-SQL con SQL Server Profiler y ejecutarlo en una nueva consulta en SQL Server, todo marcha bien. El problema esta cuando lo ejecuto desde VS.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes... La solución está en los detalles.

Resulta que Luis Cazares tenía la razón, me enfoque en las dos columnas principales: [COD_PERSONA] Y [TIPO], pero el problema estaba en la columna [AU_USU_INSERT], que almacena el nombre de usuario que registra el archivo, en el momento de creación de la base de datos la longitud designada a esta columna fue VARCHAR (10)... En la actualidad, la longitud enviada es superior.

Saludos.